# browser cant open my php project on fedora 38

Tags: php, apache, http, lamp

I've installed LAMP on my fedora 38 the localhost works fine and info.php works fine but whene I try to open my php file project from browser i just get white blank screen

i have checked http logs error and i find this errors

```
[Sun Jun 18 11:33:10.184241 2023] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 15227:tid 15227] AH00489: Apache/2.4.57 (Fedora Linux) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Jun 18 11:33:10.184284 2023] [core:notice] [pid 15227:tid 15227] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
[Sun Jun 18 11:33:10.186389 2023] [:warn] [pid 15229:tid 15229] ./mod_dnssd.c: No services found to register
[Sun Jun 18 11:42:47.304260 2023] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 15227:tid 15227] AH00492: caught SIGWINCH, shutting down gracefully
[Sun Jun 18 11:42:48.425613 2023] [suexec:notice] [pid 16097:tid 16097] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Sun Jun 18 11:42:48.456186 2023] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 16097:tid 16097] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[Sun Jun 18 11:42:48.459192 2023] [systemd:notice] [pid 16097:tid 16097] SELinux policy enabled; httpd running as context system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0
[Sun Jun 18 11:42:48.465736 2023] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 16097:tid 16097] AH00489: Apache/2.4.57 (Fedora Linux) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Jun 18 11:42:48.465818 2023] [core:notice] [pid 16097:tid 16097] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
[Sun Jun 18 11:42:48.466101 2023] [:warn] [pid 16100:tid 16100] ./mod_dnssd.c: No services found to register
[Sun Jun 18 11:53:28.338476 2023] [autoindex:error] [pid 16101:tid 16153] [client ::1:35340] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /var/www/html/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html,index.php,index.php) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive
[Sun Jun 18 11:54:21.586333 2023] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 16101:tid 16168] [client ::1:53840] AH01071: Got error 'Primary script unknown'
```